# R can't work with ecw while gdal/qgis does. Ubuntu 20.04 config

Tags: gdal, r, ubuntu, rgdal, ecw

I'm an Ubuntu 20.04 user with all configured to use .ecw raster format. I can read these files in QGIS (3.10) and work with them without a problem. This is what I get in console:

```
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28

$ gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ecw
ECW -raster- (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.4)
JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.4)
```

The issue here is that I'm trying to perform some processes with this files within R but it seems that .ecw are not working and I don't know what to do.

```
> gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = "PNOA_MA_OF_ETRS89_HU29_h50_0151.ecw", output.vrt = "dem.vrt")

ERROR 4: `PNOA_MA_OF_ETRS89_HU29_h50_0151.ecw' not recognized as a supported file format.
Warning 1: Can't open PNOA_MA_OF_ETRS89_HU29_h50_0151.ecw. Skipping it
NULL
Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  comando ejecutado '"/usr/local/bin/gdalbuildvrt" "dem.vrt" "PNOA_MA_OF_ETRS89_HU29_h50_0151.ecw"' tiene estatus 1
```

What could I check? I prefer any solution that downgrading the gdal version to 2.4 (as is Ubuntu is quite complex to make it all work and that will brake other things for sure...).

Comment: It looks like your command line `gdalinfo` and the `gdalbuildvrt` that R is finding might coming from different GDAL installations. What does `which gdalbuildvrt` say on the command line? Can you run `gdalbuildvrt "dem.vrt" "PNOA_MA_OF_ETRS89_HU29_h50_0151.ecw"' tiene estatus 1` on the command line (from where that .ecw is)?

Comment: You might be able to tell R to use a different GDAL via `gdal_setInstallation`, or possibly deleting the one that has put the binary for `gdalbuildvrt` in `/usr/local/bin/` - but make sure nothing else is using it first.

Comment: I tried to execute gdalbuildvrt "dem.vrt" "PNOA_MA_OF_ETRS89_HU29_h50_0151.ecw" in console and It worked perfectly. Something must be happening with the gdal installation R is refering. I'm not sure what should I change or how to set it. Where is the usual gdal installation in linux ?

Comment: You can get a list of possible gdal installations for `gdalUtils` here: `getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath")`. Check the `$path` element of each element in that list. Add the information I asked in my first comment about `which` to your question. You need to tell `gdalUtils` to use the right gdal.

Comment: getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath") returns this in $path -->[1] "/usr/local/bin/". which gdalbuildvrt returns this --> Error: unexpected symbol in "which gdalbuildvrt"

Comment: `which` is a command-line program, not an R function. Run it at the command line where you were running `gdalinfo` that said it had ECW support. Or run `gdalinfo --libs` there. We are trying to find out if you have multiple GDAL installations and where they live. R seems to be using one in `/usr/local/`, now to find where your shell is looking...

Comment: Sorry, here is what the terminal returns to `which gdalbuildvrt --> /usr/local/bin/gdalbuildvrt`

Comment: Hmmm. R and Shell both using /usr/local/bin/gdalbuildvrt but one doesn't have ECW drives. Is ECW in the driver list from `getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath") `?

Comment: It seems that the drivers is not here: `getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath")[[1]]$driver[grep("ECW|ecw", getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath")[[1]]$driver$format_name),]` --> `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Comment: Okay this is taking a lot to do one line at a time. What I might do is make a shell script and an R script that hopefully pulls out all the relevant data. You'd run them and put the output into the question, rather than this endless stream of comments!

Comment: @César Do you happen to have a link to how you got ecw file reading setup in QGIS 3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04?